# xbacklight -display XX?

Tags: multiple-monitors, brightness, hdmi, xrandr, xbacklight

I have two displays. I can successfully set brightness for the first display using e.g. `xbacklight -set 30`, but I cannot dim my second display connected to HDMI. I tried `xbacklight -display HDMI1 -set 30`, and `xbacklight -display 1 -set 30`, but I've got `RANDR Query Version returned error -1` in both cases.

What do I have to write as the -display parameter?

P.S.

```
xrandr --listmonitors
Monitors: 1
 0: +*HDMI1 1920/527x1080/296+0+0  HDMI1
```

The following command works perfectly:

```
xrandr --output HDMI1 --brightness 0.3
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you ever solve this?

Comment: About your P.S.: backlight and brightness are not the same thing. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/421308/270277

Comment: I just answered the same question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/562672/270277)

Comment: That's not really an answer to this question but an alternative way.

Answer (score 0):

This option is now deprecated. From `man xbacklight`:

```
-display IGNORED
       Ignored for backward compatibility.
```

You must use `xrandr`